# Silverlight Button - Change Foreground Color on hover

Tags: silverlight, button, hover, silverlight-5.0

I have created a style template for my Silverlight buttons, managed to create rounded corners and a hover state which changes the majority of the style without any issues, however...

**I cant figure out how to make the `Foreground` colour change on `hover`.**

See my code below, the part Im having issues with is currently commented out.

```
    <Style TargetType="Button" >
        <Setter x:Name="myFontColor" Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="28">
                        <Border x:Name="myBorder" BorderBrush="#C4C4C4" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop1" Color="#FDFDFD" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop2" Color="#D6D6D6" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommomStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="GradientStop1"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                    From="#FDFDFD" To="#0A284B" 
                                                    Duration="0"
                                                    />
                                        <ColorAnimation 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="GradientStop2"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                    From="#D6D6D6" To="#135887"
                                                    Duration="0"
                                                    />

                                        <ColorAnimation 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="myBorder" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    From="#C4C4C4" To="#000000" 
                                                    Duration="0"
                                            />
                                        <!--<ColorAnimation
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="myFontColor" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                    From="#000000" To="#FFFFFF" 
                                                    Duration="0"
                                            />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Being fairly new to Silverlight, Id hope this just a simple issue with targeting the correct element and style.

How do I go about getting the `Foreground` color to change on `hover`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, put the `ContentPresenter` inside a `ContentControl` (this has the Foreground Property) then you can change it just like you did with the background:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" >
    <Setter x:Name="myFontColor" Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Height="28">
                    <Border x:Name="myBorder" BorderBrush="#C4C4C4" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop1" Color="#FDFDFD" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop2" Color="#D6D6D6" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Border>
                    <!-- CONTENT CONTROL HERE -->
                    <ContentControl Name="content" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ContentPresenter  />
                    </ContentControl>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommomStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradientStop1"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                        From="#FDFDFD" To="#0A284B" 
                                        Duration="0"
                                        />
                                    <ColorAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradientStop2"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                        From="#D6D6D6" To="#135887"
                                        Duration="0"
                                        />

                                    <ColorAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="myBorder" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        From="#C4C4C4" To="#000000" 
                                        Duration="0"
                                />


                                   <!-- ALTERNATIVE WAY 

                                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Foreground)" Storyboard.TargetName="content">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->


                                    <ColorAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="content" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        From="#000000" To="#FFFFFF" 
                                        Duration="0"
                                />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dothat by adding events MouseEnter and MouseLeave and change colors in event

example:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" 
    Content="Button" 
    MouseEnter="myButton_MouseEnter" 
    MouseLeave="myButton_MouseLeave"/>
```

and in class C# you have to have methods

```
    private void myButton_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        myButton.Foreground=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    private void myButton_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        myButton.Foreground=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }
```

Hope, that it is what you looking for.

Comment: Thanks! .. my style I created is to effect all buttons within my app. Does your code accommodate for this?

Comment: it will work on all buttons wit MouseEnter and MouseLeave calling those methods, it dont has to be done directly, but can be done by calling in event handler if one of buttons has to do something else with change color on hover. To know with button is hovered, you can use object sender parameter, with is actually a button reference if i recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this, useful, although not exactly what I was looking for. +1

Comment: Although this will work you really should not do it this way, since you need to ensure every button calls these event handlers if you want all your buttons to change their foreground colour. Much better to just use a style, as per the preferred answer.

Comment: That's true. If anything could be achieved by css, it should be done that way.
in fact, what i wrote as an answer, will change css properties (if im wrong, please correct me).
However if desired actions are not visual effects, but business operations for example, my solution is just fine i think.

Answer (score 1):

Use Blend for designing any control. Using this you can easly create any style which you want

Just go through [Creating a button](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GsbhohzwBM)

Comment: Thanks for this, useful, although not exactly what I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#FF474747"/> <!--change this color code if you wish-->
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#FF474747"/> <!--change this color code if you wish-->
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#FF474747"/> <!--change this color code if you wish-->
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#FF474747"/> <!--change this color code if you wish-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="DarkGray"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="DarkGray"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="DarkGray"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="DarkGray"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" To="DarkGray"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="DarkGray"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="DarkGray"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="DarkGray"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".55"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="3" Background="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Margin="1">
                            <Border Opacity="0"  x:Name="BackgroundAnimation" Background="#FF448DCA" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" >
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#A9A9A9" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#A5A5A5" Offset="0.375" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#A3A3A3" Offset="0.625" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#A0A0A0" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter
                          x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#A9A9A9" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Margin="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```